# grant SELECT access to v$session to other users

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I want to grant SELECT access to v$session to other users in an `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

but when I run this query:

```
SELECT owner, object_type FROM dba_objects WHERE object_name = 'V$SESSION';
```

I got this error:

```
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
```

Comment: additionally to the 2 answers below, I you receive this message it probably means that you arent a DBA. `SELECT owner, object_type FROM all_objects` would than work but you would receive only a limited subset corresponding to the objects you are allowed to see.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oracle v$ views are named V_$VIEWNAME and they have synonyms in format V$VIEWNAME and you can’t give privilege on a synonym.  If you want to give permission to a V$ view you must give it like below

```
SQL> grant select on v_$session to hr;
```

Answer (score 1):

We also needed a regular user without access to v$session to cleanup sessions. A function will execute with the privileges of the owning schema, so if you create a function as the user having access to V$SESSION you can execute it from the user not having the required privilege.

For example, IFH_OWNER has access to v$session, user id854812 doesn't:

As id854812:

```
select count(*) from v$session
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

As IFH_OWNER:

```
select count(*) from v$session
56

create or replace function getSessionCount return int
as
  vCnt int;
begin
  select count(*) into vCnt from v$session;
  return( vCnt);
end;

select getSessionCount from dual;
56

grant execute on getSessionCount to id854812;
```

As id854812:

```
select ifh_owner.getSessionCount from dual;
56
```