# Oracle kill sessions procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create procedure which will kill all session. After I run the statement i get error:

> [Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error 10/13   PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 6/6     PL/SQL: SQL Statement
>   ignored 15/31   PLS-00364: loop index variable 'V_KILL' use is invalid
>   15/9    PL/SQL: Statement ignored  (1: 0): Warning: compiled but with
>   compilation errors

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE KILL_ORACLE_SESSIONS
    IS

    BEGIN
        FOR v_kill IN
        (SELECT
                'alter system kill session '''
                ||sid||','||serial#||',@1'|| ''' immediate;' as statement
                        FROM
                v$session
                    WHERE
                sql_id='sql_id_here'
        )
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line (v_kill.statement);
        END LOOP;
    END;
    /
```

Where is the catch ?
Thanks

Comment: You don't have permission on `v$session`

Comment: Just that I couldn't do GRANT SELECT ON V$SESSION TO {username}; instead I do  grant select on V_$SQL to {username};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you don't have permissions to select view `v$session` because your user received this privilege by a ROLE. Privileges inside a PL/SQL block must be granted directly to the user (i.e. `GRANT SELECT ON V$SESSION TO {username};`). A role (for example `DBA` ROLE) does not apply inside PL/SQL.

Comment: `GRANT SELECT ON V_$SESSION TO {username};` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562257/grant-select-access-to-vsession-to-other-users)